# How to add our own custom chart in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline, microsoft-graph-api, azure-pipelines

I have to create chart in Azure DevOps for showing some graph view. not for showing test pass/fail. I want to show some graph based on total volume and sales. can we create such a graph? If yes please provide some references.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and you shouldn't. Azure DevOps is not an analytics platform, it is a dev-ops platform with some analytics views.

Instead, export data from Azure DevOps with [Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/about-managed-queries?view=azure-devops) (or CSVs), then cross it with your Sales and Total Volume in your favorite analytics tool (PowerBI, Excel, Google, you decide).

Azure DevOps has some good built-in analytic tools which are built around its metamodel foundation (Work items, etc). They're easy to setup, but restrited to Azure DevOps own data objects.